# Using awk to find/replace the string in text file from defined variable

Tags: awk, csh

I have a input text file as below.

---

```
...
...
DataColumn No X Y W H Kind Ch Count1 Type Count2;
DataList 10
         1 -45268.1732  50408.958800      0.0900      0.8998 0000000000000600 00800000   2   6   1   
         2 -45020.4257 -15543.664000      0.0450      0.0463 0000000000000400 00010000   2   6   3   
         3 -44409.6520 -32404.892300      0.2475      0.2713 0000000000001b00 03000000  30  22   3   
         4 -43948.3907 -54234.067300      0.4950      0.9898 0000000000005f00 00040000  16  22   2   
         5 -41225.6319  -2571.856700      0.1125      0.1363 0000000000000604 00001000  10   0   3   
         6 -40201.3420 -27953.152800      0.1125      0.9911 0000000000000f00 02000000  12  22   3   
         7 -38914.2407  27199.880200      0.5850      0.3163 0000000000004b4b 08000000  66   2   3   
         8 -38765.5269  62329.594300      0.5175      0.2699 000000000000005f 00040000  18  22   1   
         9 -37719.1757 -56932.842000      0.0450      0.0450 0000000000000008 04000000   1   1   1   
        10 -36898.5332  14978.750600      0.1800      0.1363 0000000000000e00 00000800   7   0   3  
...
...
```

---

I want to replace the value of column "6 6 22 22 0 22 2 22 1 0" as "0 0 22 5 0 22 0 22 5 0" as bleow.

---

```
...
...
DataColumn No X Y W H Kind Ch Count1 Type Count2;
DataList 10
         1 -45268.1732  50408.958800      0.0900      0.8998 0000000000000600 00800000   2   0   1   
         2 -45020.4257 -15543.664000      0.0450      0.0463 0000000000000400 00010000   2   0   3   
         3 -44409.6520 -32404.892300      0.2475      0.2713 0000000000001b00 03000000  30  22   3   
         4 -43948.3907 -54234.067300      0.4950      0.9898 0000000000005f00 00040000  16   5   2   
         5 -41225.6319  -2571.856700      0.1125      0.1363 0000000000000604 00001000  10   0   3   
         6 -40201.3420 -27953.152800      0.1125      0.9911 0000000000000f00 02000000  12  22   3   
         7 -38914.2407  27199.880200      0.5850      0.3163 0000000000004b4b 08000000  66   0   3   
         8 -38765.5269  62329.594300      0.5175      0.2699 000000000000005f 00040000  18  22   1   
         9 -37719.1757 -56932.842000      0.0450      0.0450 0000000000000008 04000000   1   5   1   
        10 -36898.5332  14978.750600      0.1800      0.1363 0000000000000e00 00000800   7   0   3  
...
...
```

---

I can define the variable for "0 0 22 5 0 22 0 22 5 0" as 'set nextNum = "0 0 22 5 0 22 0 22 5 0"' because this variable is defined from other datas.

Here is my test code to replace the string data.

```
set new_value = "0 0 22 5 0 22 0 22 5 0"
awk -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t\t"} NR>2 {split(new_val, values); $9 = values[FNR]} {print}' ${in_file} > output.txt
```

But, I cannot get the result I want. Please refer the my result.

---

```
DataColumn No X Y W H Kind Ch Count1 Type Count2;
DataList 10
1  -45268.1732  50408.958800    0.0900  0.8998  0000000000000600  00800000  2   22  1
2  -45020.4257  -15543.664000   0.0450  0.0463  0000000000000400  00010000  2   5   3
3  -44409.6520  -32404.892300   0.2475  0.2713  0000000000001b00  03000000  30  0   3
4  -43948.3907  -54234.067300   0.4950  0.9898  0000000000005f00  00040000  16  22  2
5  -41225.6319  -2571.856700    0.1125  0.1363  0000000000000604  00001000  10  0   3
6  -40201.3420  -27953.152800   0.1125  0.9911  0000000000000f00  02000000  12  22  3
7  -38914.2407  27199.880200    0.5850  0.3163  0000000000004b4b  08000000  66  5   3
8  -38765.5269  62329.594300    0.5175  0.2699  000000000000005f  00040000  18  0   1
9  -37719.1757  -56932.842000   0.0450  0.0450  0000000000000008  04000000  1       1
10  -36898.5332 14978.750600    0.1800  0.1363  0000000000000e00  00000800  7       3
```

---

I try to get the result I want using below code and so on.

```
set defIdList_LRF = (`awk '/DataList/{i=1;next}/NR/{i=0}i {print $9}' $in_file`)
```

Is there a way to replace via my code or other code in awk?
My code environment is cshell based.

```
#!/bin/csh -fb

set in_file = "./defectlist_sort.txt"

set new_value = "0 0 22 5 0 22 0 22 5 0"
#awk -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} NR>2 {split(new_val, values); $9 = values[FNR]} {print}' ${in_file} > output.txt
#awk -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {split(new_val, values); $9 = values[FNR]} {print}' ${in_file} > output.txt
#awk -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} /DefectDataList/NR>2 {split(new_val, values); $9 = values[FNR]} {print}' ${in_file} > output.txt
```

Comment: Read [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Yikes, TMI (too much information). Please read /reflect/act on the section "How to turrn a bad script into a good question" found on the [bash.info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) . (This advice applies to many/most programming langauges, so don't worry that it is not `csh` specific). Good luck.

Comment: Less is more (-; ... do we really need 10 lines of data to solve this problem? If there are differences in processing, include just 1 record to match each case of processing. From what I can see, I think you need the header and 1 record. And we probably don't need a record that is 10 columns wide. Less is more (-;! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on OP's first `awk` script ...

Assume `NR==3` (the first time you apply your code).  At this point `FNR==3` so you'll access `values[3]` as the new replacement value for the *1st* data line of interest.  Net result is you'll never reference `values[1]` or `values[2]` thus leading to a shift (by 2 lines) of your replacement values.

Other minor issues:

- move the `split()` up into a `BEGIN{...}` block so that you only perform the `split()` once (current code repeatedly performs the same `split()` operation for every row where `NR>3`)
- since we're only dealing with one input file it may be a bit less confusing to use `NR` throughout the script (ie, no need for `FNR`)

Modifying OP's first `awk` script:

```
awk -v new_val="$new_value" '
BEGIN { OFS="\t\t"
        split(new_val, values)
      }
NR>2  { $9 = values[NR-2] }
      { print }
' "${in_file}" > output.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- this code assumes the first line in the file starts with `DataColumn No X Y ...`
- it's not clear (to me) what the `...` entries represent in the sample input file
- OP may need to replace the `NR-2` with an appropriate offset if the line starting with `DataColumn No X Y ...` occurs anywhere else in the file (ie, other than the first line in the file)
- OP's use of `OFS="\t\t"` is not going to generate what's been provided as the expected output; OP will need to clarify what's expected as output ... maintain the same spacing as in the input file ... or ... reformat with a double tab between each column ... ???
- assumes the number of entries in the `values[]` array is an exact match for the number of lines we need to modify; otherwise OP needs to provide details of what to do if there's a mismatch in the two counts

Comment: wouldnt' it be easier to just prepend 2 dummy entries for `new_val`, so the replacement could simply be `$9 = values[ NR ]` ?

Comment: six of one, half a dozen of the other ... add N positions on front of `new_val` or subtract N from the index; if OP comes back and states those `...` entries represent an uknown number of rows to be skipped/ignored, then how to determine N when prepending N dummy entries to `new_val` in the `BEGIN{...}` block? my choice would be to count the number of lines to skip/ignore and then subtract from the index; prepending N dummy entries is certainly doable but seems excessive especially if N ends up being 'large' (eg, N=1000)